# Is there a way to know the current participants in a hangout meeting?

Tags: google-admin-sdk, google-hangouts, hangouts-api

Exploratory question, I've looked through the API docs but haven't been able to find something definitive.

Is there a way to pull the current participants in a hangout meeting from the G Suite API?

Purpose would be to create an internal dashboard showing the current participants in a "virtual office" hangout that just runs all day, letting everyone know who's currently "in the office".

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to pull the current participants in a hangout meeting from the G Suite API?

#### Answer:

*As you have already discovered, there is no way of doing this.*

#### More information:

The Hangouts API is for chatbots only and doesn't have functionality to join meetings. I believe there would be security issues with allowing something like this as video calls could be recorded or viewed on without people being made aware.

As a workaround, the only thing that would be possible is to have participants join a Hangouts chat when they "clock-in" to the office, and leave again when they "clock-out" - this way you could have a chatbot grab a list of the users in the chat for the dashboard.

#### References:

- [Method: `spaces.members.list` | Hangouts Chat API](https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/reference/rest/v1/spaces.members/list)